# Android app advertisement

Tags: android, set, admob, ads

everyone! Can I ask question? I'm new in android development area)) I made one good app. My question is: how I can monetize(add advertisements) to my app?please help me. I need detailed instructions how to set up and so on)) Sorry for  my english)

Comment: Have you made any attempts at this yourself?

Comment: If you type 'admob implementation android' into Google, the first link is the answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

you can show ads in your app bu using Google's AdMob service...
now AdMob is included in Google-Play-Services-lib so , 
import google-play-services and give reference to your project ...
you can monetize your ads from signing in AdMob

XMl code:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="yourProjectIDinAdmob" />
```

Java code :

```
    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Thank you friends! I'll try this! Today my birthday. I'm sorry for late reply)))

Comment: Thank you Rajesh! You're genius!!!!! I can't vote up or do anything! Bless you! And can ask my last question about adMob: how I can get money from advertisement?Can I sent to my bank card???

Comment: Google supports only few banks in USA.. 
if your outside US, then use PayPal Account, 
create one paypal account link your bank account to paypal, give that (Paypal)email in your AdMob account.. Google will check every end of the month will transfer after once u reach $20 .. u will get it 2 months.. paypal process will take 1 week to transfer to your bank account.